# YouTube app asked me to turn on notification

Tags: youtube, popup

Yesterday, I opened my YouTube app in my Redmi Note 11, but it had a pop-up saying something like “Don’t miss the new videos, turn on YouTube notifications.” I didn’t click anything on this pop-up, I tapped the arrow button at the bottom of the screen and the pop-up was gone.

I have turned off the YT app notification for a long time and have never seen this pop-up when opening the YT app before, I don’t know if it is YT legitimate system pop-up or not.

Has anyone ever found this pop-up or know whether it is a legitimate pop-up from YT or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the YouTube app may remind the user about the notification being turned off**.

I just turned off the global notification for the YouTube app from the Android settings for the first time, and when I opened the app, I also got the same pop-up.

[image]

> **Turn on notifications**
>
> Don't miss the latest videos and more from your favorite channels.
>
> <kbd>No thanks</kbd> <kbd>Turn on</kbd>

Clicking "Turn on" will bring the user to the Android notification settings for the YouTube app directly. Looks like the pop-up will only be shown once per device. (I have 2 Android devices, dismissed on one device, and tapped "Turn on" on another. Clearing the app data/storage still didn't show the pop-up again).

---

YouTube app has shown a similar reminder previously, although not so prominent, by showing it on the app directly.

[image]

<sup>Image from [Reddit - [question] How do we disable the "Don't miss new videos" pop up? Everytime you reopen the app it's there](https://www.reddit.com/r/Vanced/comments/pac5yj/question_how_do_we_disable_the_dont_miss_new/). [Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801000000*/https://i.redd.it/9mczqa4x67j71.jpg).</sup>